# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kvbazw37\Beautifulsoup\

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I am trying to execute this command:
`pip install Beautifulsoup`
I have cmd opened in Administrator mode. But when I did it I get this:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kvbazw37\Beautifulsoup\

What my logs says is this:

```html
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install Beautifulsoup
Collecting Beautifulsoup
  Using cached BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kvbazw37\Beautifulsoup\setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-kvbazw37\Beautifulsoup\
```

I dont know what to do, please help me!

Comment: you should download a newer version of beautifulsoup, this one doesn't fit your version of python, or maybe use `pip3 install ...`

Comment: @PRMoureu Thank you for your reaction! I still got the same error when I do `pip3 install Beatifulsoup`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to `pip install bs4`? That's the latest version of BeautifulSoup.

Comment: @Rawing when I do that, I get: `Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in c:\users\aaron\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages`

Comment: so `import bs4` should work in your codes now, did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the setuptools for python?

If not, download this file and then in powershell or command prompt, navigate to ez_setup’s directory and execute the command and this will run the file for you:

$ [sudo] python ez_setup.py
If you still need to install pip at this point, run:

$ [sudo] easy_install pip
easy_install was part of the setuptools, and therefore wouldn't work for installing pip.

Then, pip will successfully install django with the command:

$ [sudo] pip install django